Instantiate php request and convert to requestinterface
I've just started php/laravel and i'm facing a huge problem. I want
instantiate a php request and Call toPsrRequest() to get a RequestInterface type.
How can i solve it please ?
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class FlowController extends Controller
{
    function headerauthorization()
    {
       //url to set inside the request
       $url = "example.com/fetch";

       //instantiate a request
       $request = new Request();
       // then i need to set the url = $url and http method=GET
       
       //convert the request instantiated to RequestInterface type
       $convertRequest = $request->toPsrRequest();

    }
}


You're confusing two things that do not have anything to do with each other.
The Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface usually exists in laravel installations, but it's not used by the framework itself.
It comes from the package psr/http-message which is then required by guzzlehttp/psr7 (directly) and by guzzlehttp/guzzle (through psr/http-client).
guzzlehttp/guzzle should already be required by laravel so there's no need to install any new dependencies for this code to work.
If you want a PSR7 request, you should just use the GuzzleHttp Request instead.
I've commented out the optional parameters with their default values.
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

class FlowController extends Controller
{
    function headerauthorization()
    {
        $request = new GuzzleRequest(
            method: 'GET',
            uri: 'example.com/fetch'
            // headers: [],
            // body: null,
            // version: '1.1',
        );
    }
}

This $request is already an instanceof RequestInterface.
You can read more on Guzzle's documentation

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

